# streaming in webview (android)

Tags: android, webview, streaming

I am trying to play livestream TV in a WebView. WebView shows a black screen livestream area in page, but it is not loading and playing the stream.

**wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());** (mainactivity)

and

**android:hardwareAccelerated="true"** (manifest.xml)  doesn't work

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setFocusable(true);
wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
wv.loadUrl("http://www.fox.com.tr/canli-yayin");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

All Live streaming is not supported in Mobile.So first check whether your URL work in chrome browser. if it is working then you can use the custom tab

```
 compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'

String url = ¨http://www.fox.com.tr/canli-yayin¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this webview settings for the video stream

```
mWebview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        mWebview.Settings.SupportZoom();
        mWebview.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebview.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        mWebview.ZoomOut();
        mWebview.ZoomIn();
        mWebview.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        mWebview.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        mWebview.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            mWebview.Settings.MixedContentMode = MixedContentHandling.CompatibilityMode;
        mWebview.Settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
        mWebview.Settings.GetPluginState();
        mWebview.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
```

And if you want to open the stream with in the application then setwebviewclient of webview.

```
 mWebview.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Event if it does not work then please set user agent string of webview

```
 webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 5 Build/_BuildID_) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36");
```